# CMake override executable command on pressing play button in the IDE

Tags: cmake, ide, clion

I use `Emscripten` c++ compiler which makes `html`/`js` files on `add_executable` targets

CLion automatically detects targets and its executables

[image: 1]

`w4-temp` executable here points on the `js` file and tries to launch it (and fails)

(CLion allows manually choose executable command but I have about 100 targets and want to automate it. Also this shoud work in Visual Studio, not on CLion only)

My question is - how to override target executable execute command inside cmake to call custom command (e.g. `python` http server inside the build directory)?

I'm thinking that solution exists and **should look a bit like** `target_set_executable_override(targetName "python -m http 8080 -d build")` but couldn't find anything in the docs

Comment: I think you need something like [add_custom_target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html), or, as an alternative, you can describe you application as CTest.

Comment: @uta add_custom_target would add another target and that would be a mess and what do you mean on describing using ctest? How can it be used in the IDE?

Comment: CTest is supported in both VS and CLion and give you a chance to run your artifact by any manner. It is a part of CMake ecosystem. If you follow this way, you get a smoke test for your application for free. 
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/book/mastering-cmake/chapter/Testing%20With%20CMake%20and%20CTest.html